# working with integers in java, seeking a method that returns the last few characters of an integer

Tags: java, android, integer

I'm trying to figure out how I could use a java program to return the last 3 digits of an integer.

So for example if I had a number like `45678` how would I be able to return `678`? Also how would I be able to determine that the length of this integer is `5` digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String s = Integer.toString(45678);
s.substring(s.length() - 3); // first answer
s.length() == 5; // second answer
```

Answer (score 9):

You can determine how many digits a number has by using [`Math.log10()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) (remember to [`Math.abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) if you're going to be dealing with negatives):

```
(int) Math.log10(45678) + 1 // 5
```

Using the modulo operator with [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) can give you the last *x* digits of a number:

```
int x = 3;
45678 % Math.pow(10, x) // 678
```

Comment: Floating point arithmetic might make the first of these imprecise.